# Asp.net Gridview with javascript function build as string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have that piece of code inside a gridview

`<%# If(Eval("t") = 1,
"<button onclick=" + String.Format("popupGO('{0}','{1}')", Eval("name").ToString(), Eval("id").ToString()) + ">" +
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</button>", "")%>`

It doesnt works if from parameters there is a string as Eval("name").ToString().

With numbers ONLY it works!!

Any suggestion?

UPDATE.
Full code with GV

```
<asp:GridView Width="100%" gvrunat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" BackColor="Transparent" ShowHeader="false"                         RowStyle-CssClass="test" GridLines="None">
<Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<%# If(Eval("tablecounter") > 1,
"<span class='badge badge-info'>" + Eval("id").ToString() + " </span>", "")%>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />                                                    
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="right">
<ItemTemplate>    <%# If(Eval("t") = 1,
"<button onclick=" + String.Format("popupGO('{0}','{1}')", Eval("name").ToString(), Eval("id").ToString()) + ">" +
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</button>", "")%>
</ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField></Columns></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I fail to understand what a GridView has to do with this. Since it's not in the question. Second enclose the property values with double quotes, as is standard.

Comment: What about using an Asp:Button and binding the onClientClick in the RowDataBound?

Comment: I could be use asp:button and manage if inside rowdatabound, but I'd to fix this, because with numeber parameter it works perfectly!

Comment: Eval("Name").ToString()

Use upper case?

Comment: but also  in this case it doesnt work  <%# If(Eval("t") = 1,
"<button onclick=" + String.Format("popupGO('{0}','{1}')", 'a', 'a') + ">" +
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</button>", "")%>

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
 <%# If(Eval("tipo") = 1, "<button onclick=" + """" + "popuptransfer('" + Eval("Nome").ToString() + "','" + Eval("IdComanda").ToString() + "') " + """" + ">" + "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</button>", "")%>
```